# How to vectorize to remove for loops in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization, linspace

I want to remove the for loops in the following Python code by vectorizing it. I searched the Stack overflow and all over the internet to find a solution to no avail.

```
for v in range(height):
  for u in range(width):
    start[v,u,0] = -0.5 + u / (width-1)
    start[v,u,1] = (-0.5 + v / (height-1)) * height / width
    start[v,u,2] = 0
```

I think we should use NumPy. Perhaps numpy.linspace() is to be used? So, what do you think?

Comment: What are all these variables to begin with? ``start[v,u,0]`` suggests you are *already* using numpy.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to read this post on how to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: It seems that you can vectorize that indexing using `ax0, ax1 = np.ogrid[:height, :width`]

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
start[v,u,0] = -0.5 + u / (width-1)
start[v,u,1] = (-0.5 + v / (height-1)) * height / width
start[v,u,2] = 0
```

works if `v` and `u` are fancy indices:

```
start = np.random.randint(99, size=(5,7,3)).astype(float)
height, width = start.shape[:2]
v, u = np.indices((height, width))
```

**Sample run (values are rounded):**

```
>>> v
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4]]
>>> u
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]]
>>> start[v,u,0]
[[-0.5  -0.33 -0.17  0.    0.17  0.33  0.5 ]
 [-0.5  -0.33 -0.17  0.    0.17  0.33  0.5 ]
 [-0.5  -0.33 -0.17  0.    0.17  0.33  0.5 ]
 [-0.5  -0.33 -0.17  0.    0.17  0.33  0.5 ]
 [-0.5  -0.33 -0.17  0.    0.17  0.33  0.5 ]]
>>> start[v,u,1]
[[-0.36 -0.36 -0.36 -0.36 -0.36 -0.36 -0.36]
 [-0.18 -0.18 -0.18 -0.18 -0.18 -0.18 -0.18]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.18  0.18  0.18  0.18  0.18  0.18  0.18]
 [ 0.36  0.36  0.36  0.36  0.36  0.36  0.36]]
```

A quick preview for better understanding:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question without more info (do you want to create the array?  Is it already created??  why are your v, u indicies 'backwards'? ...

But to answer your question, yes - there are many ways to do what you want with numpy.

Have a look below, and then go and read for an hour or two some numpy tutorials etc:

```py
import numpy as np

rows = 10
cols = 5

values = np.zeros((rows, cols, 3))

values[:,:,0] = np.fromfunction(
    lambda r, c: -0.5 + c / (cols - 1),
    (rows, cols))

values[:,:,1] = np.fromfunction(
    lambda r, c: (-0.5 + r / (rows - 1) * rows / cols),
    (rows, cols))
```

Note there are many ways to do what you want with numpy.

The above is just one, and written in a more expanded, easy to follow way.  You could do the same thing in one line probably, but it would be harder to understand if you're new to numpy.